# Can I limit the IDE to 2GB?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10-seattle

The Delphi Seattle IDE can use up to 4GB of memory, even though BDS.exe is a 32-bit program.
This is very nice for large projects but when compiling a small project sometimes the IDE goes haywire and starts consuming all available memory.

When it was limited to 2GB this would sort itself out soon enough and I'd get a `out of memory error`;restart the IDE and everything is fine.

However when running Seattle on a PC with 4GB physical RAM the out of memory condition locks up the PC for 10 minutes or more because the disk starts trashing.

**Is there a way to switch the IDE back to 2GB on PC's with little RAM inside?**

Comment: if you use Seattle Update 1 you need hotfix http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30453

Comment: @kami, thanks but the problem is an out-of-memory due to a compiler error. So that hotfix does not actually fix the issue.

Comment: Try running the IDE in XP/Vista compatibility mode, which GlobalMemoryStatus2GB is one of the shims. I'd doubt the IDE would ask for the system memory and act accordingly, but worth a try.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, interesting notion, will try.

Comment: Ugh... development on a PC with 4GB of RAM and a spinny disk?  Why oh why?  It costs practically nothing for more RAM and an SSD and it saves you so much time and frustration.  Even if you're paid modestly, investing in a sensibly spec'd development system will pay for itself in a matter of weeks for the time it will save you.  There's really no excuse for struggling with inadequate hardware.

Comment: How about just changing the priority to Idle? I would assume it allows you to intervene and recover more easily when you start noticing memory pressure.

Comment: Another, although slightly risky alternative, is to disable virtual memory. The reason why it's thrashing is because it swapping out to disk for the virtual memory. We have a number of testing machines where we disable virtual memory. If you run out of memory then you get an error indicating that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We installed Delphi on a virtual machine. There you can easily limit the memory. The virtual machine also doesn't block the whole computer. The main advantage is that you can have access from any computer in the network.

Answer (score 2):

There is no configuration switch for what you ask.  The IDE executable is marked as Large Address Aware in its PE header.  The only option would be to use a PE editing tool to remove that flag from the executable.

However changing the exe on disk triggers the copy-protection and shuts down the IDE.

Comment: But that might invalidate the digital signature, which will trigger the copy protection. I'd suggest making sure you have Update 1, which fixed a handle leak, and just keeping an eye on Task Manager and force-terminating. Also, is there a QP for this?

Comment: maybe you can find de-protected EXE. Since you legally purchased the IDE that should be considered as work on compatibility

Comment: @DavidM, keeping track of memory usage is pointless the memory runaway is so sudden by the time it I notice it the PC has already gone catatonic. It takes minutes to just respond to CTRL+ALT+DEL.

Comment: Wow. I've never seen that behaviour; is there a QP report? Does it happen with every project or just one? If just one, you can privately submit your code to Emb to help them diagnose it.